# Firebase generates new uid for diffrent facebook app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have integrated facebook login with firebase , and login with my user .  But after some time the facebook have disabled my app , there is no way to resolve that issue . Now i have made a new facebook app and now when i used to login with facebook it generates new uid for earlier logged in users . How can i get the same uid for new facebook app .